# need clearly explanation about error in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am a newbie to Angularjs. I often get this error when I try to push an object to an array.
I try many ways but I don't know what's wrong with it. 
It repeatedly gets error: $scope.todo is undefined.
[Here is my code](http://plnkr.co/edit/rvhLhuwlR7UsYtaLhKjh) (link at http:// plnkr.co/edit/rvhLhuwlR7UsYtaLhKjh)

When I add $scope.todo = {}; it can't get the title I enter and it push blank title.
Please explain in detail and clearly for me so that I can understand more about $scope and form input in controller.
Thanks

this is my module code

```
angular.module('todoApp',['ionic'])
  .controller('todoCtrl', function($scope){
    $scope.todos = [
        {title: "Go to the cinema"},
        {title: "Take some books"},
        {title: "Check out booking room"}
      ];
    $scope.addTodo = function(){
      $scope.todos.push({title: $scope.todo.title});
      $scope.todo.title = '';
    };
  });
```

Comment: when I add $scope.todo = {}; it can't get text from input and it push a blank title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as your code seems

```
$scope.addTodo = function(){
      $scope.todos.push({title: $scope.todo.title});
      $scope.todo.title = '';
    };
```

in the line `$scope.todos.push({title: $scope.todo.title});` you still dont have $scope.todo.title defined because you are defining it on the next line.

change the code to.

```
angular.module('todoApp',['ionic'])
  .controller('todoCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.todo = {};
    $scope.todos = [
        {title: "Go to the cinema"},
        {title: "Take some books"},
        {title: "Check out booking room"}
      ];
    $scope.addTodo = function(){
      $scope.todos.push({title: $scope.todo.title});
      $scope.todo = {};
    };
  }]);
```

i have edited your plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/Z1fg0rg6cUbsJJOy9wie?p=preview) have a look.
i have made changes to your HTML and script.js
http://plnkr.co/edit/Z1fg0rg6cUbsJJOy9wie?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

The problem is $scope.todo isn't defined yet.

Under the $scope.addTodo function just add:

$scope.todo = {};

$scope.todo.title = '';

After the function.  Then it is initialized.

```
angular.module('todoApp',['ionic'])
  .controller('todoCtrl', function($scope){
     $scope.todos = [
       {title: "Go to the cinema"},
       {title: "Take some books"},
       {title: "Check out booking room"}
     ];
     $scope.addTodo = function(){
         $scope.todos.push({title: $scope.todo.title});
         $scope.todo.title = '';
     };
     $scope.todo = {}
     $scope.todo.title = '';
});
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. But why when I put $scope.todo = {}; in addTodo function, it pushes blank title. It can't recognize my input?

Comment: @JamesDo It would then re-initialize it when the function is called.  If you put it below the push, it should push in the expected value.